# angularjs: can' t pass parameter to the parent controller method via '&' binding in isolated directive scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

In my angular application, I defined a directive `foo-directive`, which is placed in a parent controller as below:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent">
       <foo-directive data="parent.city" tab-click="parent.tClick()" tab-click2="parent.tClick2(v)"></foo-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

pass two method: `parent.tClick()` and `parent.tClick2(v)` into the directive and bind to `tab-click` and `tab-click2` attributes respectively. The difference is that the second one has a parameter

and the JS code goes as below:

```
function ParentCtrl($timeout){
    this.city= "London";
    this.tClick = function(){
        console.log("debugging parent tclick...");
    }
    this.tClick2 = function(v){
        console.log("debugging parent tclick2...");
        console.log(v)
    }
}

function FirstCtrl() {
    this.$onInit = function(){
         this.click = function(){
             this.tabClick();
             this.tabClick2("abc");
         }
    }
}

function fooDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            tabClick : "&",
            tabClick2: "&"
        },
        controller: 'FirstCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'foo',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<div ng-click="foo.click()">{{ foo.data }}</div>',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
            //console.log($ctrl.name);
        }
   };
}
```

Now the issue comes from the second method `this.tabClick2("abc")`. There is `TypeError` message. I have reproduced this issue with this live demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/sv4d03hk/1/

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing the functions into your directive, you should pass the "reference" to the function, rather than the "result" of the function. Adding the parenthesis, is actually *executing* the function and returning the result to the directive. As neither function returns a value, they will both be passing `undefined`.

Given that the value of the parameter you want to pass (`v`) to the function is inside the directive scope, not that of the parent, you dont need to even tell the directive that the function accepts a parameter. You just pass it to the function inside the directive. ie.

```
<foo-directive data="parent.city" tab-click="parent.tClick" tab-click2="parent.tClick2"></foo-directive>
```

[According to the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#-directives), using `&` is then you want to evaluate the result of the attribute:

> The `&` binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time.

Instead, we want to be able to execute the passed attribute, and in particular give it a variable. As such either `=` (two-way binding) or `@` (one-way binding) are probably more appropriate for what we're after.

```
tabClick: "=",
tabClick2: "="
```

You can also do away with your controller completely by updating your template.

```
template: '<div ng-click="foo.tabClick();foo.tabClick2(data)">{{ foo.data }}</div>'
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv4d03hk/3/)**

```js
function ParentCtrl($timeout) {
  this.city = "London";
  this.tClick = function() {
    console.log("debugging parent tclick...");
  }
}

function FirstCtrl() {}

function fooDirective() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      tabClick: "="
    },
    controller: 'FirstCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'foo',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '<div ng-click="foo.tabClick(data)">{{ foo.data }}</div>',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      //console.log($ctrl.name);
    }
  };
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('fooDirective', fooDirective)
  .controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl)
  .controller('ParentCtrl', ParentCtrl)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent">
    <foo-directive data="parent.city" tab-click=":: parent.tClick"></foo-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

*PS. if you're concerned about performance using `@` or `=`, consider one time bindings using `::`. ie. `<foo-directive data="parent.city" tab-click=":: parent.tClick" tab-click2=":: parent.tClick2"></foo-directive>`*

Comment: Thanks.I think I have misunderstood about the & binding. I read many tutorials and they said "The “&” prefix is also known as a method binding. This is used to bind any methods from the parent scope to the directive scope." That's the reason why I used it since I am calling a method from parent scope....so how do you think about such saying....

Comment: It definitely has its usages. I particularly use it when i want to fire bound event callbacks up to the parent

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet of code for your "FirstCtrl":

```
function FirstCtrl() {
    this.$onInit = function(){
        this.click = function(){
            this.tabClick({v: this.data});
        }
    }
}
```

As you are using an expression binding (&), you need to explicitly call it with a JSON containing "v" and it's value. like the following:

this.tabClick({v: this.data});